# Eclipse 4.2 Juno looks illegibly - while text on white background

Tags: eclipse, themes, eclipse-juno

[image: Eclipse 4.2 Juno]

**How to fix it?**

PS. Switching to another Eclipse theme changes only shape of gui but doesn't change colors.

My machine is:

```
Archlinux + XFCE 4.10
Eclipse Version: 4.2.0, Build id: I20120608-1400
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart after changing the theme? Only some changes are applied on the fly.

Comment: It helped, maybe it doesn't look perfect, but at least decenty

Comment: I've resigned from my Ubuntu 12, just because Eclipse (which I use on a daily basis) looks horrible there.

Comment: @smas: Tom Schindl might have a solution for you: http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/07/19/eclipse-4-lf-on-linux/